# Ignore words less than or equal 3 javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, bookmarklet

I'm building my own boorkmarklet for analyze the words in the current page, currently it's working good, but I would like filter the words and just show the words longer than 3 letters, I'm new with javascript but here is my code:

```
    var sWords = document.body.innerText.toLowerCase().trim().replace(/[,;.]/g,'').split(/[\s\/]+/g).sort();
    // count duplicates
    var iWordsCount = sWords.length;

// array of words to ignore
var ignore = ['and','the','to','a','of','for','as','i','with','it','is','on','that','this','can','in','be','has','if'];
ignore = (function(){
    var o = {};
    var iCount = ignore.length;
    for (var i=0;i<iCount;i++){
        o[ignore[i]] = true;
    }
    return o;
}());
```

thanks for the time !

Comment: By _"words greater than 3"_ do you mean _words that appear more than 3 times_, or do you mean _words that are longer than 3 letters_?

Comment: ohh sorry, I'm going to improve my post @StephenP but is words longer than 3 letters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **[filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)** function :

```
function greaterThanThree(element){
    return element.length > 3;
}

 var longer_words = ['f','as','i','with','on','that','this','can','has','if'].filter(greaterThanThree);

//Will return ["with", "that", "this"]
```

Hope this helps.